# How to remove logical duplicates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can we  remove logical duplicates from the below table ( ie when the from and to is same stations either of 2 rows should be returned)

```
 from_station| to _station| distance  
 delhi   |      mumbai   |   5000  
 mumbai  |      delhi    |  5000  
 delhi   |      cochin   |   3000  
 cochin  |      delhi    |   3000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have some id for get the single rows?+

Comment: What do you mean by logical duplicate? Be as specific as possible in your questions on StackOverflow to increase your chances to be answered.

Answer (score 2):

```
select   distinct

         least    (from_station,to_station)
        ,greatest (from_station,to_station)
        ,distance 

from     t
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does? Then I'll remove my 'code only answers are bad' downvote

Comment: @EngineerDollery . . . If you know SQL this answer (and mine as well) are pretty self explanatory.  An explanation that says:  "get the distinct values of the lesser of the station names and the greater of the station names" really doesn't add much to the answer.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, No. This is practically English.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- if the OP knew sql they would not have had to ask the question...

Comment: @EngineerDollery, If the OP doesn't know SQL then this is certainly not the place to teach him.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to *return* results, then you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.from_station < t.to_station
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.from_station > t.to_station and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.from_station = t.to_station and t2.to_station = t.from_station
                 );
```

An alternative mechanism uses aggregation:

```
select least(t.from_station, t. _station) as from_station,
       greatest(t.from_station, t. _station) as to_station,
       avg(distance)
from t
group by least(t.from_station, t. _station),
         greatest(t.from_station, t. _station);
```

However, this can introduce rows that are not in the original data (if only one row exists between two city pairs).

Comment: @EngineerDollery . . . Back when I had little reputation, I also made the mistake of downvoting.  I didn't realize that it really just builds animosity, causes people to ignore you, and impedes getting others to *listen* to what I had to say.  I gave up downvoting cold-turkey years ago, although I am an avid user of comments, flags, and closes.  I will note that I don't think I ever (regularly) downvoted anonymously.

Comment: @kbball - it's not trolling. The site has standards and voting is there to encourage high-quality questions *and answers*. If I don't feel an answer is good enough I have every right to downvote it. If you don't like how the site works, feel free to campaign for changes.